# How can I install a local RPM using only the local dependency RPM files?

Tags: centos, rpm

In my CentOS machine (VirtualBox VM, altough I assume this shouldn't matter), I have a directory including an RPM file and all of its dependency RPM files.

I want to install the RPM along with all of its dependencies, but I want to install only using the files in this folder (not fetching the dependencies from remote repos).

I want to do this in order to make sure that I have all of the dependencies in this folder.

How can this be done?

**Edit**

Note that I tried

```bash
rpm -Uvh /path/to/folder/*.rpm
```

but it didn't do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `yum`, by making a ".repo" repository file for your collection and running `yum` temporarily enabling *this* repository while disabling the other repositories.  You might find this simplest by making a shell script to call `yum` while disabling the regular repositories.  Use `yum repolist` to get the *names* to disable.

Something like

```
#!/bin/sh
yum --disablerepo=foo "$@"
```

(you can list more than one `--disablerepo` option).  Alternatively, you can disable all of the repositories and enable only those which you need, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
yum --disable-repo='*' --enable-repo=myrepo "$@"
```

Further reading:

- [yum - Yellowdog Updater Modified](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html) shows these options

> `--enablerepo=`*repoidglob*
>   Enables specific repositories by id or glob that have been
>   disabled in the configuration file using the enabled=0 option.
>   Configuration Option: enabled
>
> `--disablerepo=`*repoidglob*
>   Disables specific repositories by id or glob.
>   Configuration Option: enabled

- [How do I create yum repo file?](https://superuser.com/questions/451298/how-do-i-create-yum-repo-file)
- [How To Set Up and Use Yum Repositories on a CentOS 6 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps)
- [[CentOS] more than one repo with --disablerepo](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2006-April/021285.html)