# How do I install a package with the correct dependencies from a bunch of RPMs I've downloaded?

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf

I'm in a situation similar to [How can I install a local RPM using only the local dependency RPM files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281715/how-can-i-install-a-local-rpm-using-only-the-local-dependency-rpm-files) or [install a directory full of RPMs so that rpms providing dependencies are installed before dependent rpms?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358579/install-a-directory-full-of-rpms-so-that-rpms-providing-dependencies-are-install), but I'm on Fedora rather than CentOS and have DNF instead of Yum.

I have a bunch of `.rpm` files downloaded to a directory. I want to install one of them (let's say `foo-1.0-1.rpm`) and have its dependencies. I only want to install the required things, not all of the other files that have been downloaded, like `foo-debuginfo-1.0-1.rpm` and `foo-extraplugin-that-no-one-uses-1.0-1.rpm`. If I do `dnf install *`, I get all the extra junk. If I do just `dnf install foo-1.0-1.rpm`, I get errors about missing dependencies on `bar` and `baz` and `foo-essential`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

The answers for Yum suggest making a local repository and adding a repo configuration file to `/etc/yum.repos.d`. You *could* do that, but with DNF, you don't have to. You can just point to a local repo with no config file. You do need to create the repo in your directory, though.

So:

1. Change to the directory in question. `cd ~/Downloads/RPMs`, for example.
2. run `createrepo_c .` in that directory. (Or `createrepo_c ~/Downloads/RPMs` from anywhere.)
3. Run `dnf --repofrompath local,. install foo`

Notes:

`createrepo_c` is a drop-in and faster replacement for `createrepo`.

The syntax for the provided repo is reponame comma path. So you could do `--repofrompath "My Repository",/home/mattdm/Downloads/RPMs` if you like. You can also provide a URL — either a `file:///` URL or a remote one.

Remember to give the package you want installed as just the package name, like `foo`, rather than a file name, like `foo-1.0-1.rpm`.

And finally, if you have other configured repos that also provide `foo` and those are getting pulled in instead, well, that's going to be a problem in the future, but for now, you could use `--disablerepo` to get rid of the problematic other repo.